# JUnit for Excel Files creation

Tags: java, junit

I am trying a JUNIT class, which uses calls an interface in which a method '`generateexcelreport`' , builds an excel reprot based on a list of values.But when I used mockito to mock the implementation, I am getting an exception with creating a file, no w I tried using the `Mockito.doNothing()` on this method , but still Mockito calls the method and am getting the exception again.

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.io.File.mkdir()" because the return value of "java.io.File.getParentFile()" is null
```

My Method:

```
public void generateExcelReport(HashMap<String, List<Object>> hydrated) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException{

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        hydrated.entrySet().stream().forEach(key -> {
            List<Object> bodyNode = (List<Object>) key.getValue().get(0);

            Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(key.getKey().toString());

            try {
                buildExcel(bodyNode,workbook,sheet);
            } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


        try {

            File report= new File(fileName);
            FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
            if (hydrationReport.getParentFile().mkdir()) {
                fileOut = new FileOutputStream(hydrationReport);
                workbook.write(fileOut);
            }else if(Files.exists(Path.of(hydrationReport.getParent()))){
                fileOut = new FileOutputStream(hydrationReport);
                workbook.write(fileOut);
            }else {
                throw new IOException("Failed to create directory " + hydrationReport.getParent());
            }
            fileOut.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this is myy mock class, I am stuck creating it, Could someone please help

```
public class ExecutorImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    ExecutorImpl impl;

      

    @Test
    public void vlaidateHydrationTest() throws TimeoutException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        ///when

        HashMap<String, List<Object>> map =   impl.validateHydration(request);

    }
}
```

Comment: Most-likely your  `fileName` in `File report = new File(fileName);` is incorrect, somehow invalid, or `null` (although, if it was `null`, you'd be getting a `NullPointerException`). Try doing a `System.out.println(new File(fileName).getAbsolutePath());` and see if the path is really valid.

Comment: Okay but will the code create the directory there? Can I not mock that piece of code or say skip it?